# Why does the proof that an infinite set has a countable subset work when we have a choice function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Theorem*:
If a set $A$ is infinite, then there exists an injective function $f:\Bbb N \to A $, where $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.

*Proof*
Let us form the collection $\alpha$ of all nonempty subsets of $A$ . By existence of choice function we know that there exists a function

$c:\alpha \to \bigcup B= A $ ,such that $c(B)\in B $ for each $B \in \alpha$.

Let us now define a function $f\colon\Bbb N\to A$ by the recursive formula

- $f(1)= c(A)$
- $f(i) = c(A-f(\{1,\dots,i-1\}))$ for $i>1$.

*Doubt*

I don't understand how this formula defines $f(i) $uniquely in terms of $f\mid_{\{1,\dots,i-1\}}$.
 Without uniqueness recursion cant be used.

Note-

-*Axiom of choice*:  Given a collection $\alpha$ of disjoint nonempty sets,there exist a set $C$ consisting of exactly one element from each element of $\alpha$

-*Existence of a choice function* : 
Given a collection $\beta$ of nonempty sets(not necessarily disjoint),there exists a function 
$c:\beta \to \cup B$ such that $c(B)$ is an element of $B$ ,for each $B \in \beta $

Comment: You have a typo on your definition

Comment: I think it is fixed now. Whoever fixed it,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice function is fixed. So the choice of element is in fact unique. When we use this proof in a slightly more informal way, we just say that at each step we *can choose* an element to continue the recursion, and that is indeed not unique.

However, once you have fixed the choice function, $c(X)$ is a uniquely determined object. You just won't know what exactly it might be if you don't know what $c$ is doing exactly.